# How do I access the Developper's Computer?

Tags: candy-box

How can I access the Developper's Computer?

Comment: @schism Yeah, that part is throwing me off. Lets just scrap it with an edit, at which point, it's actually a useful question. (The spelling of 'developper' with two "p's" is a clear tell that an in-game answer is appropriate.)

Comment: @Retrosaur The "Developper" is a boss in the game. Use of his computer is the 'post game' such as it were. Whereas the generic 'console' can be assumed to refer to the browser console. Especially with the Chrome/Firefox line, which is irrelevant. Without 'Developper', this question is off-topic. With it, it's a relevant question.

Comment: This is going to attract a lot of "spelling fixes". Is there a way to protect the correct spelling without having to lock everything?

Answer (score 4):

If you mean the *Developper's Computer*, it is a tab that is unlocked by beating the Developper, the final boss of the game. There will be a Computer tab along with the Candy Box, Inventory etc tabs. It lets you buy "cheats" with lollipops, most of which have random effects on random parts of gameplay:

[image]

Save before you do just about anything in the Developper's computer as everything costs millions of lollipops and many things have no effects, cosmetic effects only or * negative* effects. Some bugs will however be beneficial or gamebreakingly amazing (the Sword of Randomness kills almost anything, including Yourself, in one hit)

If you mean the *developer's console* which is part of the *browser*, which many cheats use, this isn't actually part of the game as it were, it's a browser feature. But <kbd>F12</kbd> will bring it up in IE and Chrome, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> will open it in Firefox.

Comment: Ok, how do you get infinity lollipops?

Comment: @Matthew it's a dev console edit. Just type `lollipops.nbrOwned = Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY;`. A sanity check will reduce your lollipops to 0 when you load your save again though.

Comment: @Matthew An alternative is just to set it to an absurdly high number. `lollipops.setNbrOwned(1e32);` sets it to way more than enough, and it'll persist across loads.